# get values from json array

Tags: javascript, json, yui

i trying to get the `sku` from a url [www.mbsmfg.co/shop/coles-grey/?format=json-pretty](http://www.mbsmfg.co/shop/coles-grey/?format=json-pretty) (json) and show the users those values which are available under the variants for that particular product

> eg: when a user visits this page [www.mbsmfg.co/shop/coles-grey/](http://www.mbsmfg.co/shop/coles-grey/)
>   the user must be able to see the SKU in the product body.

Im using YUI for this and so far

```
function ajaxRequest() {
     Y.io('//www.mbsmfg.co/shop/coles-grey/?format=json-pretty', {
         on: {
             success: function (x, o) {
                 var parsedResponse;
                 try {
                     d = Y.JSON.parse(o.responseText);
                 } catch (e) {
                     console.log("JSON Parse failed!");
                     return;
                 }

                 for (var i = 0; i < d.items.length; i++) {
                     var htmlString = '<h1>' + d.items[i].sku + d.items[i].price '</h1>' + d.items[i].body;
                     Y.one('.product-sharing').append(htmlString);
                    alert(htmlString);
                 }

             }
         }
     });
 }

Y.use('node', function() {
     Y.on('domready', function() {
         ajaxRequest();
     });
 });
```

It doesn't alert or append the values to the div.

Can someone please tell me what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: d.items[i].sku may be the problem as I am not sure the contents of d, but if response text is parse normally without YUI, for sure d.items[i] will give an error.
Try putting null checks in if statement, for ex: if(d.items != undefined) then proceed for accessing it. Before accessing any element you should reach to that node. Also can u share the contents of d object.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking into the wrong place. This should give you the sku value.

```
d.item.structuredContent.variants[0].sku
```

Comment: Thanks.. this works but how can i iterate through the item list? coz  when i make the variants[1] it doesnt work... it works only with the first...